# Save numbered line with SED

Tags: sed

I use the command

```
sed -n "/*/{=;p}" file.txt | sed "{N;s/\n/ /}"
```

to numbering line.

**But, how to save in file or new file?**

The file contains

```
* text one
* text two
* text three
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe output of second sed to new file using ">".

Also,  there is an `nl` command in most distros that adds line numbers without needing sed.

Comment: I use `sed -n "/*/{=;p}" file.txt | sed "{N;s/\n/ /}" > file2.txt` but this file2.txt save is blank.

Comment: Does it give the right output to screen in the original version?

Comment: I was right , that he had forgotten the appointment. I edited my question. It is resolved. Thanks.

Comment: The answer is `sed -n "/*/{=;p}" file.txt | sed "{N;s/\n/ /}" > file2.txt`.